# Average intersection size

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have a set of K elements randomly taken N at a time M times; and I want to know the expected average intersection size. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get more help if you give some context for your questions.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?  But here's a hint: use linearity of expectation.

Comment: I figured it out, i had a feeling i was missing something really obvious all along but i couldn't place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to know the expected cardinality of the intersection of the $M$ sets.  Let the $K$ elements be $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_K$ and for $i=1,2,\dots,K,$ let $X_i$ be a random variable which is $1$ if $x_i$ is in the intersection and $0$ if it is not.  Then we want to compute $$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^KX_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^KE(X_i)$$ by linearity of expectation.

Take it from here.

Comment: Thank you.  Now that i see it it's obvious, i guess i was messing with combinatorials for so long i couldn't get out of that mode of thinking and see that that wasn't related to the problem at hand.

Comment: @PatrickJeeves Boy, am I familiar with that feeling.  It can really be hard to switch gears!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The $M$ times does not matter, just consider a pair of subsets.  What is the probability that one element in the first subset is in the second subset?  The expected overlap is the sum of this over all the elements, which is just $K$ times the chance for one element.

Comment: Okay i got it; at first i didn't because i interpreted this as "probability that at least one element" not "probability that a specific element."  I had a feeling that i was missing something really obvious about this for a while. but i couldn't place it.